# SwiftUI view not refreshing after function call

Tags: swiftui, view

When I call the clear function, everything works fine except that `ItemView` isn't refreshed. I have to close the `History` view and reopen it to see the row named "Clear".

So I don't understand why `ItemView` isn't refreshing? Do you have an idea?

Here's my History file:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HistoryView: View {
    @Environment(\.MOC) private var viewContext
    var card: FetchedResults<Card>.Element

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack() {
                // Something here!
                Group {
                    // Something here!
                    HStack() {
                        // Something here!
                        Button(action: { clear() }, label: { Text("Clear") })
                    }
                }
                VStack() {
                    ForEach(card.elementArray) { element in
                        ItemView(element: element)
                        Divider()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func clear() { CoreData.shared.clearHistory(card: card, context: viewContext) }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    var element: FetchedResults<Element>.Element

    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Text(element.date!, format: .dateTime.day(.twoDigits).month(.twoDigits))
            Spacer()
            if element.designation == "Create" { Text("Create") }
            // Something here!
            else if element.designation == "Clear" { Text("Clear") }
        }
    }
}

extension Card {
    public var elementArray: [Element] {
        let set = element as? Set<Element> ?? []
        return set.sorted {
            $0.date! > $1.date!
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the clear function from my CoreData Manager file:

```
func clearHistory(card: Card, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    card.elementArray.forEach {
        context.delete($0)
    }
    let element = Element(context: context)
    // Something here!
    element.designation = "Clear"
    element.card = card
    save(context: context)
}
```

Should I add an `.onAppear()` somewhere?

Comment: You should be using the standard SwiftUI wrappers such as “@FetchRequest” and “@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)” and “@ObservedObject” you are ignoring all the built in body reload features

Comment: Wrap `var card: FetchedResults<Card>.Element` and `var element: FetchedResults<Element>.Element` into separate ViewModels and conform them to `ObservableObject` protocol. Then create two viewModel prefixed @ObservedObject  properties for each view. When observable objects make changes views will be updates regarding viewModels changes.

Comment: @OleksandrYevdokymov I don't understand what you're trying to tell me. Can you show me?

Answer (score 0):

You need another `@FetchRequest` for `Element`. You can use a predicate `card = %@`.